# Mule ESB TcpConnector Timeout

Tags: java, tcp, timeout, mule

I got a problem using a client for a call to a TCP connector. The baisc timeout is 10 seconds but i need to update that value.

I've tried to manipulate any connection value, with no luck; this is my flow:

```
<mule ...>
 <context:property-placeholder location="${env}.properties"/>

    <tcp:connector name="tcpConnector" validateConnections="true"  
        receiveBufferSize="0" clientSoTimeout="0" receiveBacklog="0"
        sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="0" socketSoLinger="600000" 
        socketMaxWait="0" connectionTimeout="0" keepAlive="true" keepSendSocketOpen="true"
        doc:name="TCP connector">
        <tcp:direct-protocol payloadOnly="true"  /> 
           <!-- <tcp:direct-protocol payloadOnly="true"/>   
            <tcp:streaming-protocol/>  -->

    </tcp:connector> 
    <!-- 
    <configuration defaultResponseTimeout="60000" />
     -->
    <flow name="receiveresbFlow" doc:name="socketreceiveresbFlow" >
        <tcp:inbound-endpoint  exchange-pattern="request-response" responseTimeout="60000"
             host="${tcp.endpoint.host}" port="${tcp.endpoint.port}"  doc:name="TCP"  />
                <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String" />

        <set-property propertyName="MESSAGE" value="#[payload.substring(1,payload.length()-2)]" doc:name="Property"/>  
          <custom-transformer class="com.message.manager.MessageCreator" doc:name="toEventObject" ></custom-transformer>   
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I've the AnyPoint studio updated, and i'm using HapiPanel to call the port opened by the tcp connector (MLLP).

EDIT: as requested i add the only stacktrace i can see if and only if i put

> rethrowExceptionOnRead="true"

and this is what i get from client (because it's the client that gets the timeout from socket server...):

```
INFO  2015-06-24 09:43:45,374 [[testreceiver].tcpConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.tcp.protocols.DirectProtocol: Socket exception occured: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
ERROR 2015-06-24 09:43:45,873 [[testreceiver].tcpConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.mule.model.streaming.DelegatingInputStream.read(DelegatingInputStream.java:59)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.protocols.AbstractByteProtocol.safeRead(AbstractByteProtocol.java:133)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.protocols.AbstractByteProtocol.copy(AbstractByteProtocol.java:204)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.protocols.DirectProtocol.read(DirectProtocol.java:67)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.protocols.DirectProtocol.read(DirectProtocol.java:50)
    at org.mule.transport.tcp.TcpMessageReceiver$TcpWorker.getNextMessage(TcpMessageReceiver.java:361)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverResourceWorker.doRun(AbstractReceiverResourceWorker.java:41)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker.run(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:62)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks for cooperation!

Comment: Can you post the full error message logged by Mule when the time-out occurs?

Comment: So you have two Mules connected to each other over TCP, right? Can you show the config for the `testreceiver` flow?

Comment: No Sir, i got a two-way tcp-connector which waits for incoming hl7 message at a defined port. The client gets timeout after 10 seconds, if the mule flow gets time to elaborate the response...

Comment: So what is the `testreceiver` flow we see in the logs? A flow you've created in Mule to test the `receiveresbFlow` flow?

Comment: as i said: that is the error that gets the client, which is printed in mule thanks to "rethrowExceptionOnRead="true".
Without that attribute, mule flow doesn't show anything wrong, but the client goes timeout the same waiting the response after 10 seconds....